# VB.Net DataTable.Select returning invalid rows?

Tags: .net, vb.net, select, filter, datatable

I am selecting records from a DataTable like so:

```
Dim foundRows() as DataRow = dt.Select("country = 'United States' AND speed = 0 OR speed >= 1000 AND speed <= 2000 AND status = 'Unknown' OR status = 'Valid' OR status = 'Invalid'")
```

As you can see, I want to select records from the United States, whose speed is 0, or 1000-2000, and whose status is Unknown, Valid, or Invalid.

Unfortunatly records which do not meet those criteria are also being selected (ex: records with speeds < 1000, other countries)

What is wrong with my filter expression?  I tried adding parenthesis around the speed conditions, but maybe I needed more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use parenthesis:

```
country = 'United States' AND 
(speed = 0 OR (speed >= 1000 AND speed <= 2000)) AND 
(status = 'Unknown' OR status = 'Valid' OR status = 'Invalid')
```

Comment: Yeah that works.  I'll mark it as the answer in 7 mins thanks.  Nice icon btw.